# What is the correct manner to join Eid prayer when arriving late?

Tags: salat, fiqh, jamaat, eid

Often and we see it each time people come late to join the Eid prayer, some come late enough and pray in a new congregation, others come or arrive after the Imam has started the prayer.

My question is due to the fact that each raka'a of the Eid prayer starts with an extra amount of takbirat, is there any difference for a late comer to join the congregation (which is covered in [What is the exact manner to join the Salat Jamat after arriving late?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2705/what-is-the-exact-manner-to-join-the-salat-jamat-after-arriving-late))?

Should he/she add additional takbirs when starting?
What if one catches the 2nd raka'a ...
Assuming one should add *takbirs*, what if he/she did only the correct amount for 1st raka'a because he was no aware of being that late (in some madhhabs this amount is different see in the answers of  [Why did we do takbir three times during Eid ul-Fitr prayer?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/41037/why-did-we-do-takbir-three-times-during-eid-ul-fitr-prayer)), what are the fiqh rulings of that?

I'd be glad to know the fiqh views on how one should correctly join the Eid prayer when arriving late, if possible with an overview on the different opinions of the fiqh schools.

Comment: According to Imam Malik, al-Shaafi'a, Ahmad and other scholars, it is mustahabb to make it up after the jam'at have finished without a khutba.

Answer (score 1):

https://islamqa.info/en/138046

> There is no differentiation in this regard between the obligatory prayers, the Eid prayer, prayer for rain or any other prayer. If the one who is praying behind the imam catches up with a rak‘ah of Eid prayer, then that is the beginning of the prayer in his case; then he should get up after the imam says the salaam and do the second rak‘ah, saying takbeer five times at the beginning of it, because it is the second rak‘ah in his case.

Comment: With all respect, even if this is helpful it's a copy past of the main statement of your linked fatwa.

Comment: It is. That's why it's formatted as a quote.